# Skimage Morphological Opening by reconstruction, problem

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

I want to implement, morphological opening by reconstruction.

[image: Reconstruction Formula]

Here is the code I use for this purpose, but is doesn't output expected result. Code and images attached below. Please advice, what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('images/Initial_Image.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
se = np.ones((40,40), np.uint8)
marker = morphology.erosion(img, se)
mask = img
Opening_recon = cv.bitwise_not(morphology.reconstruction(cv.bitwise_not(marker), cv.bitwise_not(mask), method='erosion'))

'''
Output Results of each step
'''
cv.imwrite('images/01_Grayslace.jpg', img) #Step 1 - Grayscale Image
cv.imwrite('images/02_marker.jpg', marker) #Step 2 - Marker Image
cv.imwrite('images/03_Opening_recon.jpg', Opening_recon) #Step 3 - Opening by reconstruction
```

[image: Initial Image]
Initial Grayscale Image

[image: Marker Image]
Marker Image

[image: Opening By reconstruction]
Opening By reconstruction

Comment: that formula, without context and definitions for the parts, doesn't mean anything. -- your question seems to hinge on https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.reconstruction

Comment: Why all the `bitwise_not`? Why not just `Opening_recon = morphology.reconstruction(marker, mask)`?

Comment: I tried without bitwise_not (image complementation) but got the same result